# Html Code Hex always shows small rectangle

Tags: php, html, pdf, mpdf

In pdf i want to show tick mark by using code hexa ( `&#x2714;` ). But It shows as small rectangle in pdf.I tried Code
Decimal also but same result in pdf.

[image]

But shows perfectly in web page.How can i show tick in pdf?

Iam using mpdf plugin to generate pdf.  Please Help

Comment: You could use it as an image, instead of a character.

Comment: But in mpdf site,they mentioned this will support html entities.

Comment: The small rectangle normally means that the font being used does not contain a glyph for the character. Consider setting the font explicitly with CSS in your HTML document, to one that contains the character, and using a conversion tool that a) carries the style information into the PDF and b) embeds the font used.

Answer (score -1):

If you have an access to the server you work on, I recommand you to use wkhtml2pdf http://wkhtmltopdf.org/ . The usage is made easy by snappy https://github.com/KnpLabs/snappy .

It's compatible linux/mac (with some config issues with mamp, but who still use mamp?)/windows and make awesome renderer since it uses webkit !

Comment: How does recommending a different tool solve the problem with mpdf the OP explicitly refers to?

Comment: Because mpdf is not maintained ? And this solve the problem providing a better rendering.